# GradientDrawable setStroke Doesn't Work on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, graphics, drawable, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a Drawable inside an image view that I'm modifying at runtime in order to provide custom colors for a user's rank. The method for modifying this works fine on Android versions below 20, but above it the drawable fails to update consistently.

The particular method in question looks like:

```
void setColor(int color) {
    GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable().mutate();
    drawable.setStroke(14, color);
    drawable.invalidateSelf(); // make sure we redraw
}
```

As I said, this works fine before Android 20, but after Android 20 the drawable doesn't add the stroke. Is there a new method or did I forget something?

Comment: Have you tried on API 22 / L MR1? This may have been a bug specific to the initial L release.

Answer (score 1):

you should invalidate the view:

```
mImageView.invalidate();
```

Comment: At what point in the code should this happen? Invalidating does not seem to help my similar issue, anyway.